# When should you check if a view != null before implementing it?

Tags: java, android, android-view

I am looking at [Cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) to learn some new design tools and I came across this bit of code that left me wondering. The code finds a view, then checks if it is null before continuing its setup.

Why would the view ever return null, assuming it exists and the id matches?

I trust the expertise of the person who wrote this code and I assume it is not a mistake, but what is its purpose? When should I check for null values and when is it unnecessary?

```
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    if (navigationView != null) {
        setupDrawerContent(navigationView);
    }

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    if (viewPager != null) {
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
    }
```

...

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new CheeseListFragment(), "Category 1");
    adapter.addFragment(new CheeseListFragment(), "Category 2");
    adapter.addFragment(new CheeseListFragment(), "Category 3");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            menuItem.setChecked(true);
```

Comment: Eg. if in this layout the view with id nav_view is missing then findViewById(R.id.nav_view) method returns null.

Comment: You'd have to ask Chris why he did null checks on those `View`s specifically, but not all the others. You might notice that there's a TODO comment still at the top of the class, so it's probably not a completed, polished project. Maybe he intended to implement different layouts for portrait and landscape. Maybe it was just a debugging aid. Maybe something else entirely. We can't know for certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the other answers, I just want to make a point. Because we don't know the entirety of this code base I am assuming this user is writing his/her code to be modular. There are times we may want to dynamically add views and the timing of the binding causes us to be cautious. In those scenarios, we'd like to make sure the view we're trying to load isn't null.

Comment: Accepted this answer because it is the only one not repeating what I already mentioned in the question. I guess I just won't use the if statement until I get an error myself and have reason to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The view would return null if, for whatever reason, `findViewById(R.id.nav_view)` returns null. This could happen if `nav_view` is missing, for example. Since that function has the possibility of returning null, the null value is checked to avoid a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of using the below mentioned code is to make sure that the viewPager is never returning a null value before setting up which will result in the app crash. The person using this code is trying to play safe with the code and making sure that the app will work as expected and will not crash under any circumstances due to viewPager returning null value.

```
if (viewPager != null) {
   setupViewPager(viewPager);
}
```